Is it possible to create an OAuth2 account on macOS and iOS?
My e-mail server supports OAuth for login. It would be nice to replace username/password with a OAuth, the same way that other accounts such as Microsoft Exchange, Google, etc, work.
Is there a framework that allow me to implement such thing for macOS iOS? Like a custom internet account in addition to vanilla imap and the others provided by Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, etc? I saw that there was an account api, but it seems to be deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/account
Would the frameworks described here work on Mail.app?
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/472533/312340
